# Drag HTML5 element to SVG/D3

Tags: html, d3.js, drag-and-drop

I can drag a HTML5 element

```
<div id='item1' draggable='true' ondragstart='onDragStart(event)'></div>
```

to an SVG element

```
<circle ondragover='allowDrop(event)'></circle>
```

This is the script:

```
function onDragStart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.textContent);
}
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

// D3
myCircle.on('drop', function(nodeData) {
    // nodeData only gives me information about the destination circle
    console.log('Dropping something unknown on ' + nodeData.data.name);
});
```

But how do I get information about the div being dragged?

**EDIT: Solution**

Finally figured it out! Use `d3.event.dataTransfer`

```
myCircle.on('drop', function(nodeData) {
    console.log('Dropping ' + d3.event.dataTransfer.getData('text') + ' on ' + nodeData.data.name);
});
```

Comment: Not related to your question: "D3 element" is not a correct term. There is no "D3 element", but HTML element, SVG element etc... D3 can manipulate HTML, SVG, canvas... it depends on the code. I believe you meant "SVG element".

Comment: yes thank you :) sorry I'm new to D3, working on an existing large project